# Determine in Angular if specific area is collapse'd or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toggle

I have a button, ya click it and it triggers a collapse on a div. I'm trying to find a way to check if the div is expanded or not so I can change the text on the button "Show" or "hide".

Currently I'm using

```
ng-click="toggle = !toggle"
```

With

```
$scope.toggle = true;

$scope.$watch('toggle', function () {
    $scope.toggleText = $scope.toggle ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
})
```

Which sort of sorts, the issue being the collapse has an animation time so you can double click the button and have the toggle button text be out of sync with the actual state of the collapse div.

I've found aria-expended mentioned

```
var isExpanded = $(collapsableRegion).attr("aria-expanded");
```

But I don't understand what needs to be set for "collapsableRegion", and I can't find any documentation on ".attr" to understand what exactly the collapsableRegion is (ID, Name, class, etc.)

This is probably super simple.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to set the text in your controller, why not just set it in the markup?

```
<button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">{{ toggle ? 'Show' : 'Hide' }}</button>
```

Comment: Sure but this gives same result, it doesn't check if the data-toggle/target is collapsed or not, resulting in the double click out of sync text still.